# SSIS - Export large amount of data to Flat File. Heavy consumption TEMPDB

Tags: ssis, etl, flat

We got a problem.

It is necessary to load a large amount of data into a text file, the download is carried out by a query that includes several joins and filters.

The package was created according to all the rules, there is a source (OLE DB Source) and a recipient (Flat File), a script is specified in the source code in the SQL command field.

When trying to load, after a couple of minutes there is heavy consumption of tempdb database data files.

If you specify TOP 1000000 in the script, the download will be successful, if you specify more or nothing, TEMPDB consumption will start and the text file will not be filled. Perhaps you can specify some portions for uploading data?

Thank you.

I create a package and look for information, but nothing was found.

Comment: Every database is different which makes every query even more unique. Top Million rows works and 1M+1 causes excess tempdb usage? Maybe you can partition the query, just improve it in general so the full set which is ? M/B/Q rows can be exported, etc. How's the server configured, what do the query plans look like, etc etc. So many factors that can play into making this work but we lack any concrete evidence to help

Comment: OPTION (MAXDOP 1) helped solve my problem